# How do you automatically package PHP code for Joomla! using NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, joomla, packaging, joomla-extensions, netbeans-8

Using NetBeans 8, how can I create a script to do each of these things?

- While in development of a Joomla! component, I would like to make contents of the *site* and *admin* sub-directories, go into the *components* and *administrator/components* directories respectively of the local Joomla! instance.
- Create a ZIP file containing only the files for distribution.

Comment: Have a look at http://joomlatoys.com/index.php/toys/jtbuilder its an one-click packager to build any extension or package from already installed extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a scenario you should look into Phing (or even Apache Ant).

The Joomla Documentation provides some basic steps to do this in Eclipse. I am sure it can be valuable to achieve something similar in Netbeans as well.

[Extension development using eclipse and phing](http://docs.joomla.org/Extension_development_using_eclipse_and_phing)

[Joomla Ant build files](http://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_Ant_build_files)

Hope this helps a bit to get you in the right direction.